# Configuring Hibernate Connection pooling with c3p0 on Oracle10g

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am unable to get a connection pool using c3p0 with Hibernate and Oracle.  The database is Oracle 10.2, and hibernate version is 3.6.5.  When I take out the c3p0 settings from the config, it works fine.

I've tried to limit the number of connections requested and statements processed and still no luck.

Here is my config.xml and stack trace:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.check_nullability">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">BLAH</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">BLAH</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">BLAH</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <!-- c3p0 pooling - not working -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 

    <mapping resource="com/ht/hitthenet/planet/InvL1Service.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/ht/hitthenet/planet/VbbOrderAttributes.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/ht/hitthenet/planet/InvPort.hbm.xml" />
    <mapping resource="com/ht/hitthenet/planet/VbbSvcOrder.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>



- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@c7e8a7 -- Acquisition     Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:227)
...
```

Comment: You cut most of the useful information out of the stack trace. Show more of it. Also, what versions of hibernate, oracle, and oracle drivers are you using?

Comment: - Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
- org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
- java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ht.hitthenet.ReportJob.execute(ReportJob.java:73)
 at com.ht.hitthenet.ReportJob.main(ReportJob.java:134)

Comment: Hibernate: 3.6.5-FINAL, Oracle 10.2, Oracle Driver: ojdbc14-10.1.0.2.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was the database server restricted connections by IP address.